# for her addiction

Tags: meaning, postmodification

a. We heard a lot of criticism of her because of her addiction.

b We heard a lot of criticism of her for her addiction.

c. We heard a lot of criticism of her on account of her addiction.

The sentences are grammatical, but I wonder if they really mean what they are supposed to mean.

They seem grammatical to me but I have a strange problem with them. I think the last phrase in each is saying why we heard a lot of criticism of her, and not what the criticism was about.

To me the sentences are saying this:

Because she was an addict, we heard a lot of criticism of her.

They are not really saying what they are supposed to say, i.e. that she was criticized for her addiction.

I suspect that maybe (b) works. Maybe 'for her addiction' can postmodify 'criticism of her'.

This one gets the correct meaning across:

d. We heard a lot of criticism of her concerning her addiction.

Many thanks

Comment: Is there any _practical_ difference in meaning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the prepositions 'for' and 'because of'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/269414/what-is-the-difference-between-the-prepositions-for-and-because-of)

Comment: Thank you both very much. FumbleFingers, the other post is interesting and I am really happy I saw it, but it doesn't address my problem directly. I wanted to know if 'for', because of' and 'on account of' all postmodified 'criticism of her' in the above sentences. I think Kate's reply indicates that the sentences do work and the grammatical function of the phrases is immaterial.